# Opentok Open Source License?

Tags: webrtc, opentok

Looking at http://tokbox.com/ and [around](http://www.asee.org/documents/sections/northeast/2011/A-Free-Open-Source-API-for-Video-Conferencing-in-Distance-Education.pdf) the [web](http://www.killerstartups.com/startup-spotlight/tokbox-talks-opentok-api-open-source-and-that-mushy-feeling-inside/) seems to indicate that Opentok is open source. However, I am unable to find a proper license that describes this in any detail. While I have found the [Server SDK](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/server/)'s in the documentation, I can't determine if I am allowed to use it to host my own Opentok servers or how I might go about doing so.

Links:

- [A Free Open Source API for Video Conferencing in Distance Education](http://www.asee.org/documents/sections/northeast/2011/A-Free-Open-Source-API-for-Video-Conferencing-in-Distance-Education.pdf)
- [TokBox Talks OpenTok API, Open Source, And That Mushy Feeling Inside](http://www.killerstartups.com/startup-spotlight/tokbox-talks-opentok-api-open-source-and-that-mushy-feeling-inside/)

---

**Q: Is Opentok open source? If so, what kind of open source is it? Where can I find the license? Can I host my own servers?**

---

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing, not writing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My name is Byrne, I am a Product Manager at TokBox. OpenTok is a WebRTC platform in the cloud. The platform is open to developers, but the software that powers the service is not open source. We, along with our community of developers, produce and support a number of server SDKs and WebRTC client libraries that enable a variety of different integration scenarios with our service. Not all of these libraries and SDKs are open source, so all developers are encouraged to check licenses before bundling and redistributing our software.

Let me clarify one point about the Server SDKs though. The server SDKs do not enable to host  your own instance of our service. Our Server SDKs allow you to more easily communicate with our API to increase security of your application, and to enable you to get greater visibility into and control over chat sessions taking place across our network.